# App stops when launch

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to launch my APP and it never oppens, the only error that shows is :

```
        DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app/navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    WARNING: linker: app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    WARNING: linker: app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app/.MainActivity }
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
```

I don't have more apps running, I've closed the Android Studio and I've opened again and still without work.

EDITED *

```
 12-31 20:58:21.919  25772-25772/navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app, PID: 25772
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app/navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at navigationdrawer.tutecentral.com.jddsoft_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I click (MainActivity.java:76)

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Is this the problem, that returns a nullPointerException?

Comment: that's not an error, it is a warning. Restart the adb so you can access the application debug log so you can actually see what is the crash reason

Comment: Step through with the debugger and see if getActionBar() is returning null. Does you App's theme have an ActionBar?

Comment: @Karakuri The ActionBar is Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action bar is returning null. Check if you have a theme where you have the actionBar, and that it has a title.

But if you are using min SDK < 11 then you have to use the appcompat library and use the supportActionBar which you can get using getSupportActionBar() and your activity will have to extend the ActionBarActivity.

Comment: So if I change the min SDK will it work? I can change it in AndroidManifest, right?

Comment: It depends. Are you using the appcompat or not? If you have min sdk 11 or above check the first part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this, open cmd
type

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

and yes close eclipse and any other IDE's, then try to run the app

Comment: It's Android Studio, and it still not working... I've realized that in "AcvtivityThread.java" there are some errors... but i don't know if this can be the problem...